# Mix Entity Framework Linq with stored procedure

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Is it possible to mix in a single query a call with Linq to SQL and a stored procedure?

```
var query = from asset in this.Context.Assets
            let status =  this.Context.GetAssetAttributeLastStatusHistory(asset.idAsset)
            select new { asset, status };
```

Something like this, where `GetAssetAttributeLastStatusHistory` is a function import mapped to a stored procedure.

I want to to this in SQL and not in memory. In memory I could to a for each asset.

I need to perform pagination and filtering and it performs better if the query executes in the SQL Server.

EDIT:
This code generates an exception.
`Yes I did. I get an exception. LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult.. GetAssetAttributeLastStatusHistory(System.Nullable1[System.Guid])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

From what I know this occurs because the Framework cannot convert that expression to an SQL Expression.

EDIT2:

It seems this is not possible. It isn't possible in RAW SQL and neither with LINQ.
Thanks for your input.

Comment: Have you tried it?  If so what error/bad result do you get?

Comment: Yes I did. I get an exception. `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult.. GetAssetAttributeLastStatusHistory(System.Nullable`1[System.Guid])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Add that exception (and stack trace) to your question please.

Comment: Since you can't reference a StoredProc is a t-Sql query, there's no reason to think that somehow LinqToSql (or EF) would be able to, is there?

Comment: You can't? I thought you could. My bad. I'll close it. Thanks for the help. I guess then I should pass it all to a single SPROC then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ralph Shillington said.
It is not possible to mix EntityFramework Linq with calls to sprocs.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try, let me know if my answer is correct or not.

```
var query = from asset in this.Context.Assets
            join status 
            this.Context.GetAssetAttributeLastStatusHistory(asset.idAsset) 
            on asset.Id equals status.Id into g
            from g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { asset, status };
```

Comment: `status` doesn't have an Id. That Stored Procedure performs some joins with other tables and returns one or more records

Comment: the `Id` is your `idAsset` or something related with your `asset`  table. please try to figure out